# Image on PDF not showing properly

Tags: php, html, pdf

I am, once again, having problems with PHP.

I working on a PDF where i have to show a image that also appears in the webpage.

The problem is that the image doesn't show on the PDF.

In fact it is a different kind of image, it is actually more like a chart.

Everything you do in the webpage is shown in the chart and i have to print it in the PDF, but the PDF simply ignores the print command.

Example of the code in HTML(which works just fine):

```
<html>
<h3>
you can take files copies in xls or Pdf format
</h3>
<br> <a href="../useful/excel.php"> Generate excel file</a> <br> <BR>
<form method="post" action=""  target="_blank">
<input type="submit" name="pdf"  value="generate PDF " />
<input type="hidden" id="hide" name="hide">
</form><br>
<center><div id="image" name="image"><img src="../useful/createchart.php"/></div>            </center>
</html>
```

as you can see it is used a PHP file to create the chart(which is not exactly a class, it just a PHP file with some methods).

So i am kind of clueless on what i have t do to the image be displayed in the PDF.

BTW I'm working with mPDF.

And here i have part of hte code to print the PDF, thats the part that matters. it prints the tables just fine but it simply doesn't print the image.

```
<?php // create PDF report ...

if (isset($_POST['pdf'])){
 $mpdf = new mPDF();
//foreach ($showmore as $items){
$array = explode('-', $store); 
//$Result = array();
foreach ($array as $member){
    if($member != '')
 $res= $dao->getinfobynumber ('jc', $member); 
//var_dump($res);

 foreach ($res as $jcvalue){

 $mpdf->SetHeader("Tabela");
 $mpdf->SetFooter(date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'));
     $htmlpdf2 .= "     
    <table  border='1'>

        <tr>
            <th width='150'>GE</th>
            <td width='200'>". $jcvalue->getsg()."</td>
            <td width='200'><strong>Nome Curto</strong></td>
            <td width='200'>". $jcvalue->getnomecurto()."</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table border='1'>
        <tr>
            <th width='150'>Valor</th>
            <td width='200'>". $jcvalue->getpvalor() ."</td>
            <td width='200'><strong>FC</strong></td>
            <td width='200'>". $jcvalue->getfc() ."</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

        <table border='1'>
        <tr>
            <th width='150'> Jugular </th>
            <td width='117'>". $jcvalue->getjugular1() ."</td>
            <td width='117'>". $jcvalue->getjugular2() ."</td>
            <td width='117'>". $jcvalue->getjugular3() ."</td>
            <td width='118'>". $jcvalue->getjugular4() ."</td>
            <td width='119'>". $jcvalue->getjugular5() ."</td>

        </tr>
    </table>

    <table border='1'>
        <tr>
            <th width='150'>EXP3D</th>
            <td width='200'>". $jcvalue->getd3_1() ."</td>
            <td width='200'>". $jcvalue->getd3_2() ."</td>
            <td width='200'>". $jcvalue->getd3_3() ."</td>
        </tr>
        </table>

        <table border='1'>

        <tr>
            <th width='150'>EXP28D</th>
            <td width='200'>". $jcvalue->getd28_1() ."</td>
            <td width='200'>". $jcvalue->getd28_2() ."</td>
            <td width='200'>". $jcvalue->getd28_3() ."</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table border='1'>

        <tr>
            <th width='150'>Carotida</th>
            <td width='303'>". $jcvalue->getcarotida_1() ."</td>
            <td width='303'>". $jcvalue->getcarotida_2() ."</td>
        </tr>


    </table>

        <br><br>";
   }


    }

    $PDFimage = "<center><div id='image' name='image'><img   src='../useful/createchart.php'/></div></center>";
   $mpdf->WriteHTML($htmlpdf2);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($PDFimage);

    $mpdf->Output();

   }
```

here is the code to use the web page to select what you want to see and the apge chows you all the data it has avaiable from what you selected + the chart based on the data:

```
  <?php session_start();

 //this file contains the full information for the sample 
  // will include in this file simple table contains all informations 
  // also will calling function from creat table and also will call function create       chart and export to excel

  require_once '../useful/createtable.php';
  require_once '../dao/bancojc_424_dao.php';
  require_once '../model/jcdrow.php';
  require_once '../model/jc.php';
  include("../useful/MPDF57/MPDF57/mpdf.php");
  require_once '../dao/meta.php';
  ?>
  <?php
  $table = new createtable();
  $dao = new daobancojc();
  $meta = new metachart();
  $meta->resetmeta();
  $showmore =explode('-', $_GET['data']);
  $showtable =explode('-', $_GET['table']);
  $t='';
  $htmlpdf='';
  foreach($showmore as $item ){
      if ($item !=''){
   foreach($showtable as $tables) 
       if($tables == 'jc')
       {   
    $result=$dao->getinfobynumber ('jc', $item);
    $t='jc';
       }elseif ($tables == 'j3d'){
   $result=$dao->getinfobynumber ('j3d', $item);
   $t='j3d';
      }elseif($tables == 'j28d'){ 
     $result=$dao->getinfobynumber ('j28d', $item);
     $t='j28d';
      }
        $store .= '';
        foreach ($result as $return){
       $meta->insertmeta($t,$return->getsg());
       $htmlpdf= 'No:'.$return->getsg(). '<br>';
       $htmlpdf.= 'Nome Curto: '.$return->getnomecurto().' Nome Longo :  ';
       $htmlpdf.= $return->getnomelongo();
       echo $htmlpdf;
            ?>

      <table class="tabela_registros1" border=1 width=80% ><?php
    $htmlpdf.= $table->morejc($return);        
    echo $htmlpdf;        
    ?>
      </table>  <?php    $store .= '-'.$return->getsg() ;
  }
```

Comment: It would be a lot more useful if you gave us the code where you call mPDF to generate the PDF...

Comment: The code to create this image is extremely extensive and it is not my code, so even if i post it i couldnt explain everything that is inside it.

Comment: Not talking about the code to generate the image, but the one to generate the PDF.

Comment: it is updated with the current code to print the pdf.

Comment: First thing you can do is add `$mpdf->showImageErrors = true` to see errors. Beyond that, I wouldn't be surprised if mpdf had trouble with your relative pathname with the `..`. Try at least an absolute path. Also, how does the `createchart.php` script know what to chart? If it's using cookies or the like, it most certainly won't work.

Comment: the only error it shows me is this one:

mPDF error: IMAGE Error (../useful/createchart.php): Error parsing image file - image type not recognised, and not supported by GD imagecreate

Comment: Again, how does `createchart.php` know what to chart? If it uses cookies or session variables, it will most certainly fail as mpdf will appear like an unknown client.

Comment: it uses the code i just uploaded on the question( the last one), it takes some data from a database depending on what you select in the page(for example if i would like to know all the data from a certain subject) then it is show is the page and it creates teh chart.

also it is all have on this code, since i'm prety basic at programing in general i really clueless on what to do or to look at.

Comment: How does it tell that script "what you select in the page"? It's not passed as arguments to the script, so it's probably passed via cookies or session variables, which can't work. You need to modify the script so it takes the input from arguments, and pass them in the PDF generating code.